# Why doesnt this sort function work for Python

Tags: python, sorting

Please tell me why this sort function for Python isnt working :)

```
 def sort(list):
    if len(list)==0:
        return list
    elif len(list)==1:
        return list
    else:
        for b in range(1,len(list)):
            if list[b-1]>list[b]:
                print (list[b-1])
                hold = list[b-1]
                list[b-1]=list[b]
                list[b] = hold
a = [1,2,13,131,1,3,4]
print (sort(a))
```

Comment: Python version? And why are you writing your own [sort (link)](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function?

Comment: Please elaborate on "isn't working". Doesn't sort at all? Doesn't sort correctly? Crashes?

Comment: please explain the logic you are trying to implement

Comment: You should be very suspicious of any sort that runs in linear time.

Comment: Generally, one should never reimplement sort. Python has a lot of sorting built in.

Comment: @seanmcl No, you should patent and publish. Step 3: Profit!

Comment: Please mark an answer correct if you feel it has answered your question.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're attempting to implement a neighbor-sort algorithm. You need to repeat the loop N times. Since you only loop through the array once, you end up with the largest element being in its place (i.e., in the last index), but the rest is left unsorted.

You could debug your algorithm on your own, using [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Or, you could use python's [built-in sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

Answer (score 1):

Lets take a look at you code. Sort is a built in Python function (at least I believe it is the same for both 2.7 and 3.X) So when you are making your own functions try to stay away from name that function with inbuilt functions unless you are going to override them (Which is a whole different topic.) This idea also applies to the parameter that you used. list is a type in the python language AKA you will not be able to use that variable name. Now for some work on your code after you change all the variables and etc...

When you are going through your function you only will swap is the 2 selected elements are next to each other when needed. This will not work with all list combinations. You have to be able to check that the current i that you are at is in the correct place. So if the end element is the lowest in the List then you have to have it swap all the way to the front of the list. There are many ways of sorting (ie. Quick sort, MergeSort,Bubble Sort) and this isnt the best way... :) Here is some help:

```
def sortThis(L):
    if (len(L) == 0 or len(L) == 1):
        return list
    else:
        for i in range(len(L)):
            value = L[i]
            j = i - 1
            while (j >= 0) and (L[j] > value):
                L[j+1] = L[j]
                j -= 1
            L[j+1] = value
a = [1,2,13,131,1,3,4]
sortThis(a)
print a
```

Take a look at this for more sorting Fun: [QuickSort](http://hetland.org/coding/python/quicksort.html) [MergeSort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18783542/2048680)

Answer (score 0):

If it works, it would be the best sorting algotithm in the world (O(n)). Your algorithm only puts the greatest element at the end of the list. you have to apply recursively your function to list[:-1]. 
You should not use python reserved words