# How do I sort a string in alphabetical order in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical, python-3.4

I know there is a sort function:

```
>>> a = 'bags'
>>> ''.join(sorted(a))
'abgs'
```

However, I need to write mine from scratch. I think I would like to use mergesort but I'm not sure how that would work for a string in Python. E.g., can I compare characters? Can I find the middle of a string somehow?

I'm using Python 3.4.

Comment: Strings are just immutable sequences; but make your string a list with `a_list = list(a)` and go from there instead.

Comment: Will I not be able to sort the string (e.g. with this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-python) if I keep is as a string? Should I do string-->list-->sort-->string?

Comment: That question doesn't modify the result in-place, you can just pass the string directly to that function. Like `sorted()`, it'll return a list though.

Comment: I need it to be a string, though, so that I could use it to initialize my object. I just need to use the .join function, correct?

Comment: Yes, a list of strings can be joined with `''.join(list_of_strings)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could compare characters.

b > a evaluates to True in Python, and so forth.

You could first convert the string to a list, and get it's middle via its length,
do sequential comparison and then join the sorted list to get back a sorted string.

Comment: Perfect, I think that's all I need. I think I'll use something like this mergesort but for my string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-python

Comment: great..and you can also define the lists append outside the for loops for optimization. check:https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Avoiding_dots...