# A recursive function to sort a list of ints

Tags: python, recursion

I want to define a recursive function can sort any list of ints:

```
def sort_l(l):
    if l==[]:
        return []
    else:
        if len(l)==1:
            return [l[-1]]
        elif l[0]<l[1]:
            return [l[0]]+sort_l(l[1:])
        else:
            return sort_l(l[1:])+[l[0]]
```

Calling this function on a list [3, 1, 2,4,7,5,6,9,8] should give me:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

But I get:

```
print(sort_l([3, 1, 2,4,7,5,6,9,8]))--> [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 3]
```

Please help me to fix the problem, actual code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with `l.sort()` or `sorted(l)` ? I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: I am trying to define a function to do this recursively.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18783542/3191896

Comment: Your algorithm will only work on almost sorted lists otherwise you would have to run the function more than once on each list until the list is sorted

Comment: what if `l[0]` here is larger or smaller than other elements in `l[1:]`? that's what causes the error.

Comment: Your sorting algorithm does not work conceptually. If it is not true that `l[0]<l[1]`, then you return `sort_l(l[1:])+[l[0]]`, putting `l[0]` at the end of the list. But just because `l[0]>l[1]` does not mean `l[0]` is the highest item in the *entire* list!

Comment: Here's a recursive python implementation of QuickSort http://stackoverflow.com/a/18262384/3651800

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is recursive and easy to implement in Python:

```
def quick_sort(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    else:
        return quick_sort([e for e in l[1:] if e <= l[0]]) + [l[0]] +\
            quick_sort([e for e in l[1:] if e > l[0]])
```

will give:

```
>>> quick_sort([3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 5, 6, 9, 8])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you would want to use merge sort. Essentially in a merge sort you recursively split the list in half until you have single elements and than build it back up in the correct order. merge sort on has a complexity of `O(n log(n))` and is an extremely stable sorting method.

Here are some good in depth explanations and visuals for merge sorting:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxENKlcs2Tw
- http://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Merge_sort.html

Answer (score 1):

```
def maximum(lis):
    if len(lis) == 1:
        return lis[0]
    return maximum(lis[1:]) if lis[0] < lis[1] else maximum(lis[:1] + lis[2:])

def sorter(lis):
    if len(lis) == 1:
        return lis
    x = maximum(lis)
    lis.remove(x)
    return sorter(lis) + [x]
```

with functional programming:

```
sor = lambda lis: lis if len(lis) == 1 else [lis.pop(lis.index(reduce(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y, lis)))] + sor(lis)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def quicksort(lst):
    "Quicksort over a list-like sequence"
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return lst
    pivot = lst[0]
    pivots = [x for x in lst if x == pivot]
    small = quicksort([x for x in lst if x < pivot])
    large = quicksort([x for x in lst if x > pivot])
    return small + pivots + large
```

Above is a more readable recursive implementation of Quick Sort Algorithm. Above piece of code is from book Functional programing in python by O'REILLY.
**Above function will produce.**

```
list=[9,8,7,6,5,4]
quicksort(list)
>>[4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort(array, index = 0, bigNumber = 0):
  if len(array) == index:
    return array

  elif bigNumber > array[index]:
    array[index - 1] = array[index]
    array[index] = bigNumber
    bigNumber = array[0]
    index = 0

  else:
    bigNumber = array[index]

  return sort(array, (index + 1), bigNumber)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65255634/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

#sort an int list using recursion

```
global array
array=[5,3,8,4,2,6,1]
def sort1(array:[])->[]:
    if len(array)==1:
        return 
    temp=array[-1]
    array.pop()
    sort1(array)
    sort2(array,temp)
def sort2(array:[],temp):
    if len(array)==0 or temp>=array[-1]:
        array.append(temp)
        return
    a=array[-1]
    array.pop()
    sort2(array,temp)
    array.append(a)
sort1(array)
print(array)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here i am explaining recursive approach to sort a list. we can follow **"Induction Base-condition Hypothesis"** recursion approach. so basically we consider our hypothesis here **sort_l(nums)** function which sorts for given list and Base condition will be found when we have singly number list available which is already sorted. Now in induction step, we insert the temp element (last element of list) in the correct position of given list. 
example-

1. `sort_l([1,5,0,2])` will make below recursively call
2. `sort_l([1]) <-- 5` (here you need to insert 5 in correct position)
3. `sort_l([1,5]) <-- 0` (here you need to insert 0 in correct position)
4. `sort_l([0,1,5]) <-- 2` (here you need to insert 2 in correct position)
5. `sort_l([0,1,5,2])` Finally it will be in sorted list.

====== Below is working code=======

```
def insert_element(nums, temp):
    if len(nums) == 1:
        if nums[0] > temp:
            nums.insert(0, temp)
        elif nums[0] < temp:
            nums.append(temp)
    else:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] > temp:
                nums.insert(i, temp)
                break
        if nums[-1] < temp:
            nums.append(temp)


def sort_l(nums): ## hypothesis
    if len(nums)==1: ## base condition
        return nums
    temp = nums[-1]
    nums.pop()
    sort_l(nums)
    insert_element(nums, temp) ## induction
    return nums
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complementary answer since both `quicksort` and complexity are already covered in previous answers. Although, I believe an easy-to-get `sort` function that covers Python's identity is missing*.

```py
def sort(xs: list) -> list:
    if not xs:
        return xs
    else:
        xs.remove(num := min(xs))
        return [num] + sort(xs)
```

[*] *Python is a (slow) interpreted language, but it has become famous because of its readability and easiness to learn. It doesn't really "reward" its developers for using immutable objects nor it is a language that should be used for computation intensive applications*

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive solution. For an explanation, refer to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AZ4jEY_JAVc&list=PL_z_8CaSLPWeT1ffjiImo0sYTcnLzo-wY&index=7) video:

```py
arr = [3,1,2,4,7,5,6,9,8]

def insert_fn(arr, temp):  # Hypothesis
    if len(arr) == 0 or arr[-1] <= temp:  # Base - condition
        arr.append(temp)
        return arr
         
    # Induction
    val = arr[-1]
    arr.pop()
    insert_fn(arr, temp)  # Call function on a smaller input.
    arr.append(val)  # Induction step
    return arr

def sort_fn(arr):  # Hypothesis
    if len(arr) == 1:  # Base - condition
        return arr
    
    # Induction
    val = arr[-1]  
    arr.pop()
    sort_fn(arr)  # Call function on a smaller input.
    insert_fn(arr, val) # Induction step
    return arr

print(sort_fn(arr))
```

Comment: Thank you for linking to the video! Please summarize the explanation here on StackOverflow as well.