# Sort list a into ascending order by value using recursion instead of a loop in python

Tags: python

How to sort a list into ascending order by value using recursion instead of a loop in python?
For example, to sort [2,0,1] to [0,1,2].

```
def sort(a):  

    pos = 0
    if pos == 0 or a[pos] >= a[pos - 1]:
        pos += 1
        return sort(a)
    else: 
        a[pos], a[pos-1] = a[pos-1], a[pos]
        pos -= 1
        return sort(a)
```

Here is what I wrote and I know it does not work because the pos is always equal to 0 at first.
How could I fix it?

I test the code below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOfdj.png)

Comment: Imagine that you had someone else's `sort` function to use, instead of making recursive calls. Could you think of a way to use that `sort` function on some sub-list (or sub-lists), and combine the results to get a sorted list? All you do is write that, and then realize that you can make recursive calls instead of using the external function - because it does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26858358/a-recursive-function-to-sort-a-list-of-ints/26858588#26858588), [Quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is an example of recursive sorting algorithm and can be implemented in Python like this:

```
def quick_sort(l):
    if len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    else:
        return quick_sort([e for e in l[1:] if e <= l[0]]) + [l[0]] +\
            quick_sort([e for e in l[1:] if e > l[0]])
```

Comment: If you are copying someone else's work, atleast give a credit.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26858588/8472377

Comment: @Austin done :)

Comment: @Austin If this is the same answer, then this question should be duped.

Comment: @RoadRunner: Yes.

Comment: Actually, I tried this program. However, it seems does not work. I have attached the screenshot about what I had.