# How to improve Merge Sort speed in python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-3.x, optimization

Yes, it is homework, but I ended up doing it in Java just to get it done, but now the python implementation is bothering me. I'm pretty sure I've implemented it correctly, but it takes way longer than it should. On 3 million inputs it take on anywhere from 25 to 32 seconds. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way I'm splicing, and appending to the list. I have the source code here, let me know if you see anything.

```
def merge_sort(seq):
    if len(seq) == 1:
        return seq
    left = merge_sort(seq[:len(seq) // 2])
    right = merge_sort(seq[len(seq) // 2:])

    return merge(left, right)


def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    left_count = 0
    right_count = 0
    while len(left) > left_count and len(right) > right_count:
        if left[left_count] > right[right_count]:
            result.append(right[right_count])
            right_count += 1
        else:
            result.append(left[left_count])
            left_count += 1

    while len(left) > left_count:
        result.append(left[left_count])
        left_count += 1

    while len(right) > right_count:
        steps += 1
        result.append(right[right_count])
        right_count += 1

    return result
```

Comment: Why do you think 25-32 seconds is way longer than it should take?

Comment: Because, my prof said it was way too long (I asked to make sure). The java implementation takes around ~5.

Comment: So you were given your choice of languages? A 5-6 times improvement moving to Java doesn't seem too bad to me. That said, you could probably speed things up a lot by avoiding copying data around.

Comment: Yeah. I'd just like to try to get it down to under 10 seconds. Not that it means anything, since I'd generally just use pythons Tim sort. But more of an educational exercise. Since where I work we use python on most of our projects, it would be good to know how to optimize anything involving list anyways.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-python

Comment: BTW your code doesn’t run. It isn’t even indented properly. Please fix.

Comment: Well.. It does run. But it was copied and pasted so some of the formatting may have been messed up, but I will fix it.

Comment: If you could use `yield` instead of appending to a result, it might run faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. Slicing creates a new list containing the elements sliced. This is necessarily a costly operation.

In Java, there is no general slicing feature. However if you used `List.subList` that would return a view of the original instead of a copy and I would presume be much faster. In-place array manipulation, would be faster still.

Comment: I'm also going to try initialising the results list completely instead of extending it with append when I get home. Finished the assignment yesterday, but this has been bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
while True:
```

instead of

```
while len(left) > left_count and len(right) > right_count:
```

makes it about 40-45% faster for me:

```
def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    left_count = 0
    right_count = 0
    try:
        while True:
            if left[left_count] > right[right_count]:
                result.append(right[right_count])
                right_count += 1
            else:
                result.append(left[left_count])
                left_count += 1
    except:
        return result + left[left_count:] + right[right_count:]
```

That last line doesn't seem to make it faster, but I like it a lot better.

Comment: That seems like a terrible idea. Using a try catch block, and then intentionally throwing an `IndexError` to break? That's just sloppy.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem No, that's **[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp)**. And faster. Which is what the question is about.

Comment: With this new code from @StefanPochmann it's running at 7.2 ~ 7.3 seconds for 1 Million numbers.  (PC is Acer Aspire E15)

Answer (score 0):

From the prior thread linked to by Rishav Kundu:

---

You can initialise the whole result list in the top level call to mergesort:

```
result = [0]*len(x)   # replace 0 with a suitable default element if necessary. 
                      # or just copy x (result = x[:])
```

Then for the recursive calls you can use a helper function to which you pass not sublists, but indices into `x`. And the bottom level calls read their values from `x` and write into `result` directly.

---

For this to work, the parameter to the seq array needs to be a reference to seq and also the helper array.

You can also add a parameter to keep track of what direction to merge, so that the copy back step is avoided. C example using mtoa flag that means merge from b to a (if false, it means merge a to b). On my system, Intel 2600K 3.4ghz, this code sorts 4 million pseudo random 32 bit unsigned integers in about 0.36 seconds, and 16 million in about 1.6 seconds.

```
void TopDownMergeSort(int seq[], size_t n)
{
int * b;
    if(n < 2)
        return;
    b = malloc(n * sizeof(seq[0]));
    TopDownSplitMerge(seq, b, 0, n, true);
    free(b);
}

void TopDownSplitMerge(int a[], int b[], size_t ll, size_t ee, bool mtoa)
{
size_t rr;
    if ((ee - ll) == 1){                    // if size == 1
        if(!mtoa)                           //  copy to b if merging a to b
            b[ll] = a[ll];
        return;
    }
    rr = (ll + ee)>>1;                      // midpoint, start of right half
    TopDownSplitMerge(a, b, ll, rr, !mtoa);
    TopDownSplitMerge(a, b, rr, ee, !mtoa);
    if(mtoa)                                // if merging to a, merge b to a
        Merge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);
    else                                    // else merge a to b
        Merge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);
}
```

Another option would be to use bottom up merge sort, which skips the recursion steps and just starts merging even runs with odd runs, with an initial run size of 1.

Answer (score -1):

This is 2.7x faster than the op's code and 2x faster than @Stefan Pochmann 's

```
def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    left_count = 0
    right_count = 0

    try:
        while True:
            result.append(right[right_count] if left[left_count] > right[right_count] else left[left_count])
            right_count += left[left_count] > right[right_count]
            left_count += left[left_count] <= right[right_count]
    except:
        return result + (left[left_count:] if len(left) > left_count else right[right_count:])
```

Comment: Did you actually test that code? If `right_count` is incremented on line 9, then the condition on line 10 is testing the wrong element, which sometime leads to both counts being incremented in the same iteration, thereby dropping the left element on the floor.