# Problems with MergeSort in Python-3

Tags: python, sorting, mergesort

I have a problem with MergeSort in Python-3.x. This is that the algorithm does not do the sorting. What's my mistakes? Can you help me?

The code is:

```js
def mergeSort(lista):
 #Precondición: elem comparables
 #Postcondición: lista ordenada
 if len(lista) < 2:
  return lista
 medio = len(lista) // 2
 izq = mergeSort(lista[:medio])
 der = mergeSort(lista[medio:])
 return merge(izq,der)

def merge(lista1,lista2):
 #Precondición: listas ordenadas
 #Postcondición: retorna lista con elem de lista1 y lista2
 i,j = 0,0
 resultado = []
 while i<len(lista1) and j<len(lista2):
  if (lista1[i] < lista2[j]):
   resultado.append(lista1[i])
   i += 1
  else:
   resultado.append(lista2[j])
   j += 1
       
 resultado += lista1[i:]
 resultado += lista2[j:]
 return resultado

L = [6,7,-1,0,5,2,3,8]
mergeSort(L)
print(L)
```

And the result is:

```js
[6, 7, -1, 0, 5, 2, 3, 8]
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: Have a look at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-python).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mergesort Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `print(mergeSort(L))`. It gives `[-1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]` for me.

The problem with the following code is that `L` is not even modified. The **return value** of `mergeSort(L)` (presumably) gives you the sorted list.

```
L = [6,7,-1,0,5,2,3,8]
mergeSort(L)
print(L)
```

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right because this doesn't change it, it just orders it. Now I understand. Thank you very much for your answer.