# Second Part of Merge Sort

Tags: python, mergesort

Hi i´ve got a little problem, i wonder how would be implemented just second part of merge sort, i mean by it like input would be  array like this [[1,2],[4,5],[2,3],[5,8]] and it merge together arrays and sort them using base principe of merge sort.

Comment: You implement it with a merge function that takes two lists and outputs a single one in order.  What is it about this that you don't understand?

Comment: Hint: how to merge two list into one : use `list.extend`

Comment: `list.extend` doesn't merge two lists; it just concatenates one on to the end of the other.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Concatenating two lists isn't the same as merging them.  To merge them, the individual values need to be compared, and the smallest needs to be appended to the result list at each step so that the merged list is sorted.

Comment: You can read about [merge sort here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)

Comment: Take a look at the `heapq` module: it provides a `merge` function.

Comment: You're not the first person to try implementing merge-sort in Python, so have you looked at other SO posts about this already? E.g. [Mergesort with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761766/mergesort-with-python)